# Code groovy in JSR233 PostProcessor is not executed when jmeter test-plan is built with maven

Tags: maven-plugin, jmeter-plugins, maven-assembly-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin, jsr223

I have a project jmeter which performs for each route's HTTP request a lot of groovy code with JSR223 Post Processor

This performing works very fine when I work with jmeter GUI or non-GUI mode, and it is consolidated in my test environment.

Now I'm passing to build this jmeter project with maven, but I'm facing that the groovy code in JSR223 post processor is not performed, and this is not good for the process, because the rest of next routes are not able to work properly, because for example some variables are not set.

What are the steps to configure in maven process to build and/or interpret groovy code? and in general: JSR233 Post-processoe, pre-processor and other similar pre/post processor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin) you don't need to do anything, [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) will be executed just line in GUI or non-GUI mode.

In case you're under impression that they are not executed - take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it should be under `target/jmeter/logs` folder, if a JSR223 element fails - you will see the failure reason there.

Comment: Hi @Dmitri, yes in effect I have moved the order of routes and it worked better. The root cause was in a http POST request , which failed and then not triggered nested and next groovy code.
So, strangely the POST doesn't work in the maven build project, respect the GUI and non GUI mode. It fails with error code 403 - Forbidden. In GUI mode I have prevented handling XSRF TOKEN and _csrf token. May be that in maven build is needed some prereq to prevent error code 403 for POST requests? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue.
The root cause was in a http POST request , which failed and then it didn't trigger nested and next groovy code.

The POST was failing for an error code 403 (Forbidden) .

Then I have observed that was necessary to import in the project by pom.xml the variable:
<CookieManager.save.cookies>true</CookieManager.save.cookies>

which allows the project to handle the cookies.

In effect when I was working with Jmeter in GUI mode, that variable was set in user.properties file under /bin folder and it was working fine